# While Loop Doesn't End when i call my function

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to get input from the user but the while loop keeps going endlessly. Here is my code:

```
def player_Input():
    marker=""
    while marker != "X" or marker !="O":
        marker = input("Player-1: Please Choose X or O: ").upper()
    if marker == "X":
        print("X","O")
    else:
        print("O","X")
```

When I call this function, the input doesn't end and keeps going on continously

Comment: ``marker != "X" or marker !="O"`` can never be False. If ``marker`` is ``"X`` then it cannot be ``"O"`` and vice versa. Use ``and`` instead of ``or`` to require *both* conditions instead of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `or` to `and`in while loop:

```
def player_Input():
    marker=""
    while marker != "X" and marker !="O":
        marker = input("Player-1: Please Choose X or O: ").upper()
    if marker == "X":
        print("X","O")
    else:
        print("O","X")
```

Answer (score 2):

The Pythonic idiom for checking whether a value is in a set of accepted values is `in` / `not in`:

```
def player_Input():
    marker = None
    while marker not in ("X", "O"):
        marker = input("Player-1: Please Choose X or O: ").upper()

    if marker == "X":
        print("X", "O")
    else:
        print("O", "X")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
def player_Input():
    marker=""
    while marker not in['X','O']:
        marker = input("Player-1: Please Choose X or O: ").upper()
        if marker == "X":
            print("X","O")
        else:
            print("O","X")
```